# PowerShell icon missing from taskbar

Tags: powershell, taskbar

Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

I installed PowerShell 3 by installing Window Management Framework 3.0 (Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu)

Somehow the PowerShell icon has gone missing from the taskbar.

Attempted to re-install WMF3 but the installer simply says it's already installed ( no remove or repair option ).

How can I restore the PS3 icon ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you still run PowerShell?  If so, you could just pin it to the Taskbar while it's running.

Otherwise, you can manually create a shortcut here: **C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar** (pointing to %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe).

Comment: Thanks Joshua that worked. I wonder why only the \v1.0\ folder is present. `$Host.Version` indicates that PS3 is installed, as expected.

Comment: I've always wondered that, myself.  It's been that way since 2.0.  Glad to hear it worked! :)